# Angular 5 and Server-Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular5, server-side-rendering

There is a lot of material out there on server-side rendering (SSR) and Angular, however, much of it seems to be dated.

I've created an Angular 5 website using Firestore2 and host on Firebase. This being my first Angular site, I've not had any experience with SSR, so I'm looking for advice on how to implement it.

From what I've read, Angular Universal is now baked into Angular 5. I also understand that there is a module to avoid HTTP requests being made twice. Finally, I understand that lazy loading requires different implementation than the router. I'm using the RouterModule, declaring the titles, descriptions, routes, and components all inside of my module.ts file:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { 
        path: '', 
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
          title: '###',
          description: '###'
        }
      },
      { 
        path: 'about', 
        component: AboutComponent,
        data: {
          title: '### - About',
          description: '###'
        } 
      },
      { 
        path: 'products-and-services', 
        component: ProductsServicesComponent,
        data: {
          title: '### - Products & Services',
          description: '####'
        }  
      },
      { 
        path: 'world-class-laundry', 
        component: LaundryComponent,
        data: {
          title: '### - World Class Laundry',
          description: '###'
        }  
      },
      { 
        path: 'contact', 
        component: ContactComponent,
        data: {
          title: '### - Contact',
          description: '###'
        }  
      },
      { 
        path: 'privacy-policy', 
        component: PrivacyComponent,
        data: {
          title: '### - Privacy Policy',
          description: '###'
        }  
      },
      { 
        path: '**', 
        component: NotFoundComponent,
        data: {
          title: '### - Page Not Found',
          description: 'This page does not exist.'
        }  
      }
    ])
  ],
```

Is there a specific method that I should follow to set up server-side rendering? I don't need anything fancy. This is a very basic site. In fact, I'm only using the Firestore2 to store contact info from the contact form. All of the content in each component is hard baked HTML.

Comment: angular-cli has "ng generate universal" feature. It's a good entry point.
Refer to https://formationjavascript.com/angular-server-side-rendering-node-express/ to setup and https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-universal-server-side-rendering for transferState.
I made an sample for (angular + universal + lazyload + ngx-translate + localize-router) : https://github.com/gilsdav/angular-universal-localize-router

Comment: You can refer to official guide too : https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: Yeah you can use https://angular.io/guide/universal and if not then GoogleChrome just launched Rendertron to serve the rendered pages to Bots.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron